# Loading Buttons on window loaded event depending on Number of User

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

[image]We have WPF application, We want functionality like below.
I want one form, which will contain **Users name** & **one Button** in front of each User.
Means if Database have 10 Users, it will bring this 10 user when window load , & in front of each user there will be show button.

Comment: WPF can do all of that, good luck

Comment: But how, please help me.

Comment: what part do you need help with, The whole thing??, just put the Users in a `ListBox` and create a `DataTemplate` with a `Label` and `Button`

Comment: No, but which control I need to use, means easy for this, I have count of no of user, but how to show button in front of them?

Comment: Okay, but does it load show button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListBox` and create a `DataTemplate` containing your `Label` and `Button`

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication16.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication16"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Window.Resources>

        <!-- DataTemplate for User object -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:User}" >
            <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" Width="100"/>
                    <Button Content="Show User" Width="100" Margin="2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <!-- The ListBox -->
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<User> _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Load users
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User " + i });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set { _users = value; }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Result

[image]